# Changing coefficient values in root finding

Tags: python, scipy, sympy, nonlinear-optimization, calculus

I have the following code below:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sc
from scipy import optimize


def fun(cd, pd, cr,  p1, lambda1,prev,n2, inspIdx):
    n1 = prev + n2
    deltan1 = cd*pd*lambda1*(1-p1)*n1 - cr*(1-pd)*(1-p1)*lambda1*n1*np.exp(-lambda1*pd*n1)
    deltan2 = cd*pd*lambda1*(1-p1)*n2 - cr*(1-pd)*(1-p1)*lambda1*n2*np.exp(-lambda1*pd*n2)
    return p1**inspIdx * deltan1 + (1-p1**inspIdx) * deltan2
```

`n2` is the variable I want to find the root of this nonlinear function. However, the values of other variables change at every iteration and they're inside a for loop in the main function.

I checked SymPy but couldn't figure it out how to change coefficient values. How can I assign the coefficient values and find the root with respect to `n2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you could do it like this:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import root

# given values for the other variables
cd = pd = cr = p1 = lambda1 = prev = inspIdx = 0.5

# find the root of the function n2 -> fun(...,n2,..)
# res.x contains the root
res = root(lambda n2: fun(cd, pd, cr, p1, lambda1, prev, n2, inspIdx), x0 = [0.0])
```